# What are good alternatives to Cloud Custodian?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, cloud, cloudcustodian

I recently created an AWS account and I need a tool that can help me manage my AWS instances (EC2, RDS, Load Balancer). Specifically, I want the tool to be able to act as an instance scheduler with the following requirements:

- Ability to automatically start and terminate instances at the start/end of a business day
- Instances should automatically be deleted after specific amount of time
- A way for me to add exceptions to the rules on the fly (In the event that I need to access the server outside of normal business hours).

I recently came across Cloud Custodian which seems to satisfy these requirements by creating rules within the tool. I've also considered creating AWS Lambdas which are triggered by Cloudwatch events, however it is too expensive to maintain. Do you guys have any other suggestions or alternatives to Cloud Custodian (preferably open source) which can accomplish these tasks?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like cloud custodian solves all your needs (including provisioning the lambdas for the policies), so why the need for an alternative? vs just using custodian. it can do off hours, termination after time, exceptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a jenkins job that runs cloud custodian natively on the server thereby side stepping the Lambda and CloudWatch expenses.

Answer (score 0):

Run cloud custodian with gitlab containers. The only thing you need to set up a single ec2 instance with role access and attach this as a gitlab runner.